# Java Loop Number square ( reversed order ) each line

Tags: java, loops, numbers

So i was wondering about how do i make this...

i found this code on the internet that gives me a number-square pattern

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Square {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int a;
        
        System.out.print("Input :");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        
        for (int iOuter = 1; iOuter <= a; iOuter++) {
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
                
                System.out.print(i);
                
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    
}
```

this is the output if i put in 5

```
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
```

im looking for this output

```
12345
54321
12345
54321
12345
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apart from your requirements please also state your question. What solutions did you try? Why did they not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for (int iOuter = 1; iOuter <= a; iOuter++) {
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
                if (iOuter % 2 == 0) { // if is even
                    System.out.print(1 + a - i);
                }else {// if is odd
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

This will make diifferent things for odd and even rows.

Answer (score 0):

This simply converts the value to a String and uses StringBuilder to reverse it.

```
int val = 54321;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(val);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.println(sb.reverse());
}
```

Prints

```
12345
54321
12345
54321
12345
```